# What does maven'spring-cloud-security depency do in jhipster microservices?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster

When I was researching the microserives generated by jhipster, I found that the maven spring-cloud-security depency package was not used in Gateway. When I commented out spring-cloud-security depency, the Gateway project not report an error.

JHipster version: v6.1.0
Architecture：Microservices with Gateway and UAA

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
**<!-- <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-security</artifactId>
</dependency> -->**
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I think the spring-cloud-security depency is unused depency in Gateway.